# function that prints out numbers based on binary

Tags: ruby, algorithm

I would like to be able to generate a list of numbers that contains a specific number "x" in its binary code.

For instance, 4 (0100) is part of 5 (0101), 6 (0110), and 7(0111), but not 8 (1000).

I would like to create a function that accepts an argument "n" i.e. 8 and compiles a list of all of the numbers between say 1..1000 that use "n" in them.

Something like 8 9 10 11 12 13 14 15 24 25 26 ...

It appears like the pattern is something like (starting from "n") print next "n" numbers skip next "n" numbers, then print next "n" then skip next "n".

Is there a simple way to make this work?

For 1 (0001) it would be pretty easy like:

```
(1..1000).each do |x|
  puts x if x % 2 == 1 
end
```

However it doesn't appear to be as simple for larger numbers.

I was thinking something along the lines of (containing pseudo code):

```
def binary_count(n) 
  (n..1000).each do |x|
    #pseudo code
    next n.each do |y|
      puts x
    end
    skip next n
    repeat
  end
end
```

Any input would be much appreciated thanks.

Comment: @SirUncleCid thats question is a totally different question

Comment: You do want to re-write `to_s(2)`, so it's semi-valid. I think you need to consider how binary numbers work and write the code to implement that. Hint: `1 << n` will give you a bit in the right position. `m & (1 << n)` will be either 0 or a numerical value, so you can use that to see if the bit is set or not.

Comment: @tadman thanks for the hint. I am not familiar with "m & ()" method can you please direct me to where I could find out more about it? Thanks

Comment: The documentation on [`Fixnum#&`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Fixnum.html#method-i-26) isn't super detailed, but it doesn't really have to be. That's the *binary-AND* operator. If you're unfamiliar with binary logic, might be worth reading up on that to get a handle on how that works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Explanation:

(1..100) is a range of numbers.  We can call .to_a on it to use it as an array.  We then select the elements of the array where the element 'e', when bitshifted three to the right and logically and'ed with 1, equals 1.

```
irb(main):009:0> (1..100).to_a.select{ |e| ((e >> 3) & 1) == 1 }

=> [8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 24, 25, 26, 27, 28, 29, 30, 31, 40, 41, 42, 43, 44, 45, 46, 47, 56, 57, 58, 59, 60, 61, 62, 63,
72, 73, 74, 75, 76, 77, 78, 79, 88, 89, 90, 91, 92, 93, 94, 95
```

]